# Hide radio button on show jframe

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jradiobutton

I'm using netbeans 8. I have 2 radio button that I want to hide when the frame is shown. How can I do that? I successfully do that when I click other button such as this:

```
private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jRadioButton3.setVisible(false);
    jRadioButton4.setVisible(false);

}
```

but that's not what I want. I want to set it to invisible and only show it when I click other radio button. For some reason netbean prevent me from editing certain area in my source code so I can't test or explore it. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: @YassinHajaj - I want to set radio button invisible as default. That's mean when a frame is open 2 radiobutton can't be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `JRadioButton` `setVisible` method as `false` by default and then change it when an action is performed.

For example, here under, the `JRadioButtons` will be visible once the first `JRadioButton` is selected. If it is deselected, they disappear.

I did it with a `JRadioButton` but it can be done with other components of course.

### Solution

```
public class Test extends JFrame{

    private JRadioButton but1, but2, but3;

    public Test(){
        setSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        initComp();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComp() {
        but1 = new JRadioButton();
        but1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                but2.setVisible(but1.isSelected());
                but3.setVisible(but1.isSelected());
            }
        });

        but2 = new JRadioButton();
        but2.setVisible(false);

        but3 = new JRadioButton();
        but3.setVisible(false);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        pan.add(but1);
        pan.add(but2);
        pan.add(but3);

        getContentPane().add(pan);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Netbean allowed me to edit     `public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
      
    }`

so I put `jRadioButton3.setVisible(false);
    jRadioButton4.setVisible(false);` in there. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set the radio button to invisible when you add it to the frame and make it visible on some event:

```
public class InvisibleRadioButton {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JRadioButton jRadioButton1 = new JRadioButton("1");
    JRadioButton jRadioButton2 = new JRadioButton("2");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(jRadioButton1);
    frame.add(jRadioButton2);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    jRadioButton1.setVisible(false); // initialize as invisible

    jRadioButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jRadioButton1.setVisible(true); // set it to be visible
        }
    });
    frame.pack();
}
}
```